# Problems with a REST request in windows phone 8 using C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, windows-phone-8

I am trying to access to some rest services of a specific web server for my `WP8` app and I can´t do it well. For example, this is the code that I use when I try to login the user. I have to pass a string that represents a `Json object` ("parameters") with the username and the password and the response will be a json object too. I can't find the way to pass this pasameters in the rest request. 
This is the code;

```
public void login(string user, string passwrd)
{

    mLoginData.setUserName(user);
    mLoginData.setPasswd(passwrd);

    string serviceURL = mBaseURL + "/service/user/login/";

    string parameters = "{\"username\":\"" + mLoginData.getUserName() + "\",\"password\":\"" + mLoginData.getPasswd() + "\"}";
    //MessageBox.Show(parameters);
    //MessageBox.Show(serviceURL);
    //build the REST request
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceURL);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    //async request launchs "Gotresponse(...) when it has finished.
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GotResponse), request); 

}


private void GotResponse(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        string data;
        // State of request is asynchronous 
        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(ar))
        {
            // Read the response into a Stream object. 
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            responseStream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string exception = e.ToString();
        throw;
    }
}
```

I tried too with the `webClient` and the `httpClient` classes too but without any result.
Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the HttpClient class. This is the code.

```
public async void login(string user, string passwrd)
{


    string serviceURL = "";
    string parameters = "";

    HttpClient restClient = new HttpClient();
    restClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(mBaseURL);
    restClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, serviceURL);
    req.Content = new StringContent(parameters, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    string responseBodyAsText = "";
    try
    {
        response = await restClient.SendAsync(req);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        string ex = e.Message;
    }
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode==true)
    {
        dynamic data = JObject.Parse(responseBodyAsText);

    }
    else
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User or password were incorrect");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NNetwork connection error");
        }
    } 
}
```

I wasn't setting the header values of the request correctly.
I hope this can help someone.